# Displaying images to Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I am currently working on a C# asp.net website that has a File Upload control, a grid view, a "Image Name" textbox and a "Upload" button. The functionality of this webpage is to use a file upload to upload an image which is sent to a sql database. The grid view then displays the image ID, Image Name, and the Image from the database. I have successfully completed that portion of the project. However, my problem now is I want users to only be able to see the uploads that they have selected rather than all the images that are stored on the database... I strictly want the latest entry from the database to show on the grid view! How would I be able to do this???? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would persist the image that you are uploading to the SQL server so it won't require a second round trip of that data.  However if you want to get it out the database then the query you are using to populate the field should be modified and a `WHERE` or `JOIN` clause added to limit your result to the exact image you want.  I would also caution not to take the last image inserted because what if you have 2 users submitting images simultaneously?  I would ensure you write your query for images specific to the user and then select the latest.  If you post your query(s) people will almost certainly help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this would be to filter the rows directly from database itself. In order to do that you will also have to store the name of the user who uploaded the image.

For extracting the data, safe way would be to create a stored procedure which accepts username, queries the data which is filtered by username and then gives the output back to the application. You can also do it using parameterized query directly from the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 column_name FROM table_name
```

Comment: Please add more details as why this is an answer to the question. Adding just the code is not sufficient. Also, the code does not look like it will work in the scenario explained above.